# NextJs: Adding value whenever it's object is on clicked

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm currently working on how add the value when it is on clicked. However, I've tried to add a conditional statement between to capture whether the value is on clicked but I guess I'm missing something or I just targeting it's value not the object.

```
<Row>
    <p><b>Account Verification</b></p>
    {
        verifications.map(record => {
            return(
                <Col xs={12} md={3} mb={3}>
                    <Form.Group
                        key={record.id} 
                        className="mb-3" 
                        controlId={record.verifyName}
                        >
                        <Form.Check 
                            id={record.verifyName}
                            onChange={e=> {
                            const value = e.target.value;
                            collection.push(value);
                            console.log(collection)
                        }}
                        key={record._id} tag="verify" value={record.verifyName} label={record.verifyName} />
                      </Form.Group>
                </Col>  
                )
        })
    }
</Row>
```

What I did so far is add an if statement and wrap the collection array but it didn't worked.

```
if(value.checked == true) {
   collection.push(valued)
}
```

Need help on this. The system currently accepts data whether is checked or not as long as you click the value.

Comment: Where does `Form.Check` come from? Have you tried checking for `e.target.checked` instead?

Comment: I'm using nextjs. It's working! Could you please tell me how would I remove the value if it's unchecked?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @juliomalves, your answers worked perfectly!

```
if(e.target.checked == true) {
    collection.push(value);
} else {
    for( var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++){
        if ( collection[i] === e.target.value) {
            collection.splice(i, 1); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `collection.splice(collection.indexOf(e.target.value), 1)` to avoid the loop.

Comment: I see. Could you also please help me, once submit button is clicked, how to remove the checked values? I mean unchecked them? or is there a way to add it to my function? I am getting issues targeting them.